# Check if user is logged in and do something, else... WP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I know this question has been asked before but previous answers did not solve this problem.
My question is simple:

On wordpress (header.php) I want to check whether there is a guest or user logged in. Depending on the response I want to add/show or hide elements. My code (example) looks something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
           // ONLINE AS A USER
          } else {
            // ONLINE AS A GUEST
                $( ".grid-ibx__item-3" ).wrap( "<a href='#login_panel' class='kl-login-box'></a>" );
          }
            //$( ".box" ).wrap( "<a href='#login_panel' class='login-box'></a>" );

});
```

The console is giving me this error message:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: is_user_logged_in is not defined**
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69814/check-if-user-is-logged-in-using-jquery

Comment: This worked!
I fixed the issue by adding <?php body_class(); ?> to my body-element:
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

...and manipulating the js-code like this:

if ($('body').hasClass('logged-in')) {
       //execute your jquery code.
}


Thank you!